# 2015 Sharepoint Broken Usage Reports

Tags: sharepoint-online, reports, site-usage

I manage a sharepoint site where I have been monitoring the site usage for the past month, every day it has had 100+ views displayed on the weekly usage report I publish. However for the last week it has displayed 0 under the 'site visits', even though I and many others have been on the site.

Is this a common issue, and if so how can I fix this?

Comment: Hi Harry, in the title of your question you mention 2015. What does 2015 mean?

Comment: Harry, can you add more information to your question, please? 1) Is the site in question a classic or a modern site? 2) is it a Team site or a Communication site? 3) Is the site connected to a Microsoft 365 group? 4) Is your tenant a government tenant?

Comment: Hi, I am running the 2015 version of Sharepoint. It's a team site for my internal team at work.

Comment: hi Harry, there is no SharePoint 2015 version. Perhaps you mean SharePoint 2013? Where is your SharePoint hosted? Is it SharePoint Online or on-prem?